# Passing images from one adapter to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a gridView on my mainScreen fragment which contains imageViews initialized by my ImageAdapter.java class. I also have another fragment which also has a gridView which follows the same initialization process. What i want is to pass the selected imaveView's icon(which is stored in an Integer[] array) to the other fragment's gridView.

Here are my classes:

MainFragment.java [the part that handles the image passing]:

```
  // When an item in the context menu gets selected, call a method
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Get some extra info about the contextMenu
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int position = info.position; // clicked view's position

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to GLB")) {
        addCardMessage(position, "added to GLB");
        addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(position);
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to JP")) {
        addCardMessage(position , "added to JP");
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Creates a snackbar message, telling the user which card was added to which box
 * @param id The position of the chosen card
 * @param text Defines into which User Box the card was added
 */
private void addCardMessage(int id, String text) {
      final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(gridView, id + " " + text ,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

      snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    snackbar.show();
}


private void addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(int position) {
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext());
    UserBoxGlbImageAdapter userBoxGlbImageAdapter = new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(getContext());
    userBoxGlbImageAdapter.getGLBIconsList().add(imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(position));
    int glbiconSize = userBoxGlbImageAdapter.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected icon: " + imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

ImageAdapter.java [above fragment's adapter]:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(225, 225));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

public Integer getmThumbIds(int index) {
    return mThumbIds[index];
}

// References to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.mipmap.turvegitossj_phy,
        R.mipmap.goget_ur_int,
        R.mipmap.turgogetassj4_teq,
        R.mipmap.turgotenksssj_uragl,
        R.mipmap.lr_phy_trunks_ssj
};
}
```

SecondFragment.java:

```
public class UserBoxGLBFragment extends Fragment {

GridView globalGridView;

public UserBoxGLBFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_box_glb, container, false);

    globalGridView = view.findViewById(R.id.userBoxGlbGridView);
    globalGridView.setAdapter(new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(getContext()));
    return view;
}

}
```

SecondFragmentAdapter[the one to receive the image]:

```
public class UserBoxGlbImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;

public UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mGLBIcons.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

// References to the images via a List
private List<Integer> mGLBIcons = new ArrayList<>();

// Used to add card icons from the mainScreenFragment
public List<Integer> getGLBIconsList() {
    return mGLBIcons;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(225, 225));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mGLBIcons.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
}
```

So far, when i long-press and the context menu opens, i click on add card to GLB but the image doesn't pass to the 2nd fragmnet's gridView. From what i understand, the Integer that i am using to add the imageResource to the 2nd grid does not work properly. What do i need to do? Do i need to use a different var type for my receiver list?

Comment: mGLBIcons is empty

Comment: @diegoveloper but i need it to be empty at the beginning and then the user can add to it. Am i missing something?

Comment: How you are adding images on UserBoxGLBFragment?

Comment: i'm adding the image(as an integer) to the UserBoxGLBFragment's adapter's mGLBIcons list when the user clicks on the first item of the context menu on the mainFragment

Comment: @diegoveloper any ideas? still haven't figured it out

Comment: We need more infor, maybe you could put more classes an explain a little bit?

Comment: @diegoveloper of course, i think it may help. I'm updating the post right now!

Comment: @diegoveloper hey, if you don't mind check my new question, i believe this sums up my issue much better -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506942/converting-an-integer-to-a-drawable/47507078?noredirect=1#comment81970919_47507078 . I'll delete this old one :D

Comment: Ok I will check in a few hours

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the value correctly? Put the code

Comment: @diegoveloper are we talking about the other post? (if yes then yeah the Integer's value gets passed into the List correctly(i get an Integer like 29791..). What code do you need, i didn't understand