# Converting an Integer to a Drawable

Tags: java, android, integer, android-adapter, android-drawable

I have two Adapter classes and in the first one, i have an Array of Integers[] named mThumbIds which is initialized like this :

```
    // References to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.mipmap.beyondthe_ferocious_flash_majin_vegeta_icon,
        R.mipmap.full_tilt_kamehameha_super_saiyan2_gohan_youth_icon,
        R.mipmap.merciless_condemnation_goku_black_super_saiyan_rose_and_zamasu_icon,
        R.mipmap.everlasting_legend_super_saiyan_goku_icon,
        R.mipmap.indestructible_saiyan_evil_legendary_super_saiyan_broly_icon
};
```

I want to extract an Integer from this array(let's say mThumbIds[0]) and then pass it into my other adapter class and use it to get a valid drawable that i can use for my imageViews.

This is the 2nd adapter's List to hold the extracted Integer:

```
    // References to the images via a List
private List<Integer> mGLBIcons = new ArrayList<>();
```

And here is where i need the drawable :

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(225, 225));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
     imageView.setImageResource(mGLBIcons.get(position));
    return imageView;
}
```

So far, nothing that i've tried has worked so i am asking for your help!

*EDITED*

ImageViewAdapterClass:

```
public class UserBoxGlbImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;

public UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mGLBIcons.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

// References to the images via a List
private List<Integer> mGLBIcons = new ArrayList<>();

// Used to add card icons from the mainScreenFragment
public List<Integer> getGLBIconsList() {
    return mGLBIcons;
}

    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(225, 225));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
     Drawable drbl = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mGLBIcons.get(0));
     imageView.setImageDrawable(drbl);
    return imageView;
}

public void passInteger(Integer integer) {
    mGLBIcons.add(integer);
}

}
```

GridSettingFragmentClass:

```
public class UserBoxGLBFragment extends Fragment {

GridView globalGridView;

public UserBoxGLBFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_box_glb, container, false);

    globalGridView = view.findViewById(R.id.userBoxGlbGridView);
    globalGridView.setAdapter(new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(getContext()));
    return view;
}
}
```

fragment_user_box_glb.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorSecondaryGLB"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.dcv.spdesigns.dokkancards.ui.UserBoxGLBFragment">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/userBoxGlbGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so `setImageResource` is not working or what?

Comment: you can use `context.getResources().getDrawable(someId)` to get the drawable.

Comment: @pskink it doesn't work for what i am trying to achieve here, sadly

Comment: @Vucko it should be answer.

Comment: @Vucko i've tried something similar like `Drawable drbl = getResources().getDrawable(mThumbIds[0]);`and then inside the getView() method i changed the setImageResource to : `imageView.setImageDrawable(drbl);` but i was getting an exception that the resourceID wasn't valid

Comment: Well in that case you're not filling the array with proper values somehow. Try debugging and placing a breakpoint at that line. Try holding `alt` and clicking on the expression to evaluate it. Check if it'll throw an exception or proceed. When it does throw, you gotta figure out why, cause that's the proper way to do it.

Comment: dont put images in mipmap, put in drawable folder. Because you are using mipmap id and fetching from drawable

Comment: DEBUG  here `imageView.setImageDrawable(drbl);`.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i tried that but i don't see the debugger stopping there at any point

Comment: @pskink i am following @Manoj Kumar 's answer so i am not getting the exception right now. But i remember that it was something like : ResourceNotFound : Resource Id : 0x00 (something similar) pointing at this line `imageView.setImageDrawable(drbl);`

Comment: Could you put the logcat?

Comment: @diegoveloper i don't get neither an exception nor an error so will the logcat be useful?

Comment: Hmm it's very weird. 3 things, 1. Put the images into drawable folder . 2. Use mGLBIcons.get(0).intValue() to get the drawable or set the ImageResource.  3. Put the xml layout fragment_user_box_glb

Comment: 1) already did , 2) already tried it, didn't work(i expected that to work to be honest) neither way and 3) i'm posting it above right now

Comment: Did you try using your drawable directly in your getview method? imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable)? Does it works?

Comment: I will try it but that's not what i am trying to achieve, instead of a predefined image i want the user to be able to choose it. However for testing purposes why not test it

Comment: Did you try? Let us

Comment: I did, but nope nothing. I guess the issue is actually the imageView not getting initialized with the Integer value?

Answer (score -1):

you are using mipmap id and you are trying to load it as a drawable, i doubt it will work. try putting the images in the drawable folder and use thr drawable id.

this is how you set a drawable image in a adapter:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_success))
```

in your case it would be

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(listOfImages[position]))
```

Change your constructoras:

```
public UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(Context c, List<Integer> iconsList) {
    mContext = c;
mGLBIcons = iconsList;
}
```

try using as below:

image_view_layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp" />

</LinearLayout>

public class UserBoxGLBFragment extends Fragment {

GridView globalGridView;

List<Integer> listOfimages = new ArrayList<>();
public UserBoxGLBFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_box_glb, container, false); 
    listOfimages.add(R.drawable.beyondthe_ferocious_flash_majin_vegeta_icon);
    globalGridView = view.findViewById(R.id.userBoxGlbGridView);
    globalGridView.setAdapter(new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(getContext(),listOfimages));
    return view;
}
}


public class UserBoxGlbImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;

// References to the images via a List
private List<Integer> mGLBIcons = new ArrayList<>();


public UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(Context c,List<Integer> listOfIcons) {
    mContext = c;
    mGLBIcons = listOfIcons;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mGLBIcons.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}
// Used to add card icons from the mainScreenFragment
public List<Integer> getGLBIconsList() {
    return mGLBIcons;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout, parent, false));

        } 
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view)
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);     imageView.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mGLBIcons.get(0)));
            return imageView;
   }


}
```

Comment: alright so this is what i changed: i placed one image into the drawables folder and initialized the mThumbIds[] like so : 
    `private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.beyondthe_ferocious_flash_majin_vegeta_icon
    };` . Then inside the class that uses the adapter containing the above array, i wrote this to get the id : `        Drawable drawable = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(0));
        userBoxGlbImageAdapter.sendDrawableValue(drawable);` . But when i do : `imageView.setImageDrawable(getDRBL());`

Comment: nothing changes, my imageView remains empty but i get no errors, i'll try debugging it again but if you have any other suspicions on what i am doing wrong, please let me know

Comment: that doesn't work either sadly. It seems correct to me but it just doesn't and i get no exceptions what so ever

Comment: can u post your entire adapter code and gridview adapter setting code

Comment: you ve not added any icons into mGLBIcons list

Comment: yes, i need it to be empty at the beginning. Is that wrong?

Comment: you are not settin the images list to any image its empty so you are not able to display any images. check the updated answer

Comment: I tried something l(please check the post at ImageViewAdapterClass) but it doesn't work either(the Integer's value passes in correctly but the image is never set) :`

Comment: just one question before i start trying your newly updated answer, i don't have an ImageView in my layout, i just have a gridView which contains imageViews generated and initialized by the adapter, so do i need the findViewByID part for the imageView?

Comment: you can do it lik that also but sometime creating views in adapter using code will be bothersome, if you ve a xml in tht u will be able to control the initializations.

Comment: i'm thinking about it because i'm gonna have like 100 images inside the grid. If i were to do it via xml wouldn't i need 100 different imageViews?

Comment: no it does not work lik tht adapter reuses the layout that you are giving, only you need to change the image that is enough. i mean set the image to the imageview

Comment: um, i just realised that you only have an ImageView in your layout file while i need a gridView for my app. Is there another way to doing the same thing? I'm really confused with my issue it's been bothering me for weeks

Comment: i ve given you the code only for adapter and how to set it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159893/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-and-stelios-papamichael).